# When to use pivot tables in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have a one-to-many relationship for `Gym` to `User` relationship. That being a `Gym` can have multiple users, but a `User` can only have one gym.

Is it better to have a pivot table for this to link `gym_id` to `user_id` like follows?

`Gym_User` Table:

```
gym_id  |  user_id
```

or in the `User` table like follows?

`User` Table:

```
id | name | password | gym_id
```

Comment: You should use pivot tables when you have a many-to-many relationships. So in your case, if a User can have multiple Gyms and Gyms can have multiple Users; that's a good time to use a pivot.

Comment: @Liren So in this case dont use one? Users can only have one gym but gyms can have many users

Comment: @Packy - if you tell some more information about your requirement like what information you want to collect, then may be I can give you a simple query to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pivot tables are used when having many-to-many relationship.But for your case, you have One-to-many relationship. And don't need a pivot table.

A typical example of many-to-many relationship is Article & Tags. Where 1 article can have many tags and 1 tag can belong to many articles.

But yours is simple one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You have a 1 to many relationships, in this case you donot need pivot table, gym_id is foreign key in the user table and you will define relations on the models.

In gym model you will define a hasMany relationship to user model and in user model define belongsto relationship to gym model. (Refer to Laravel documentation).

One of nice example for pivot table is Access Controller Models
Such as User,Role and Permission..